# Creating a program that will tell a user what month it will be x months from now ( C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am completely stuck / lost. I need to write a program that will tell a user what month it will be in x amount of months from March. I need a point in the right direction to start me off.

I am still learning c++, so I'm trying to keep it as basic as possible. Any help will be a lifesaver !!

Example:

User enters 6, the result would display September.

User enters 239, the result would be February.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the input % 12 and add it to March . For example in case of 239 :

239 % 12 = 11    ---> 11 months after march is february.

Logic : there are 12 months in an year. So march will again come in a cycle of 12.

Now so n/12 years will pass as it is. So after n/12 years you will be again at march. After that only n%12 months remain. So you can add them up directly to get your answer.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier if you rebased with January as zero, did your mod 12 calculation, then converted back to January as 1, to give an answer 1 thru 12.   `month = ( ( input + 2 /* march == 2 when jan == 0 */) %12 ) +1;`

Comment: I've gotten the mod part. Its the adding it to the current month and returning the different month which I am a little confused with.

Comment: @user5959783 : I am sorry I didn't get your question

Comment: @PriyanshGoel  I am trying to write a program that takes a users input which would be equal to number of months, add it to the Current month which is defaulted as March , and then return the new month.

Comment: just think in terms of jan=0, feb=1, mar = 2 ... dec =11 in the part where you do your mod 12 calculation.   Then add the 1 to that answer to get the jan=1...dec=12 type answer

Comment: Is a numeric answer for the month OK, or do you want a noun?   Then you'd want to make a array of strings, and index into it with the zero based month number.

Comment: @user5959783 : Updated with more explanation

Comment: @infixed : I am leaving it upto him to implement it in what ever way he want. I am just trying to show him the pattern and the logic that can be used to solve the problem .

Comment: @user5959783 : Did this hep you?

Comment: @PriyanshGoel  It gave me the start I needed.

Comment: @user5959783: Then please accept this as the answer.

Comment: @infixed thank you as well!!!!!